# JQuery .click for links using this keyword

Tags: jquery, click

As you can gather from the title, I'm using JQuery's .click function to handle someone clicking a link in my navigation bar.

When the link is clicked JQuery loads in a specific section of a different html file into the content div of the main page. The code I've came up does what I want, but I'm a novice in JQuery, and I'm wondering how to do this without having to create a variable to hold everything.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#content').load('bio.html .content'); // fill #content when page loads

    $('#heading a').click(function(){ 
        var x = $(this).attr('href') + " .content"; 
        $('#content').load(x);
        return false; 
    });
});
```

I was trying to figure out how to do something like $('#content').load($(this.attr('href')) .content);. However, I couldn't get it to work properly, so I ended up creating the variable you see above, which is fine, but I'd like to keep things concise.

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is...

```
$('#content').load( $(this).attr('href') + " .content" );
```

... what you're trying to do?

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to do. Originally I did have it as $(this)., but for some reason I changed it. However, I never had the + in there because I thought I couldn't use it in there like that... should have tried it!  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to concatenate the string with the return from jQuery's method.

```
$('#content').load($(this).attr('href') + " .content");
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution is fine.

Could be simplifed like this:

```
$('#content').load($(this).attr('href') + " .content");
```

However... that doesn't mean you should.  You can write some very complex stuff in a single line of code, but if it isn't readable afterwards, you're just creating future problems.

I wouldn't have any issues leaving it as you had it.

Comment: Thanks for the insight... for this project I think I will change it because it will be a very simple project. In the future, however, I will keep what you said in mind.